# Command line session Linux from Mathematica

Tags: remote-access, command-line, run

Using `RemoteConnect` and `RemoteRunProcess` I can create a remote session such that successive commands are done in the same terminal session. I can for instance change directory with `RemoteRunProcess` and then later do `ls` from that directory. It is probably a really trivial question but how do I do the same locally. `RunProcess` does not seem to work the same. (Both in that I can't create a session with memory and in that it does not seem to accept complex commands.)

Comment: You would change directory with `Directory[]` and list files with `FileNames[]`. I think I'm missing something in your question.

Comment: I think I understand now. I think you want `StartProcess`.